# Does the kan extension preserves contractible presheaves?

Tags: simplicial-stuff, simplicial-presheaves

Let $\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{D}$ be two small categories. Let $f\: : \: \mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{D}$ be a functor. Then it induces a functor
$$
f^{*}\: : \: sPsh(\mathcal{D})\to  sPsh(\mathcal{C})
$$
via $f^{*}(X)=X\circ f$. Now consider $sPsh(\mathcal{D}), sPsh(\mathcal{C})$ equipped with the projective model structure. Then $f^{*}$ is a right Quillen functor and its left adjoint is given by the left kan extension 
$$
f_{!}\: : \: sPsh(\mathcal{C}) \to sPsh(\mathcal{D}).
$$
Assume that $X$ is a cofibrant replacement of the final functor $*\in sPsh(\mathcal{C})$. Then 
$f_{!}(X)$ is again cofibrant.

Q: When is $f_{!}(X)$  again a cofibrant replacement of $*$?

Comment: May we assume that $sPsh(\mathcal D)$ means simplicial presheaves on $\mathcal D$?

Comment: yes $sPsh(\mathcal{D})$ is the category of simplicial presheaves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$f_!(X)$ is a cofibrant replacement of $*$ if and only if the comma category $f/d$ has a weakly contractible classifying space, for all $d\in D$.

Indeed, the value of $f_!(X)$ on $d$ is weakly equivalent to the homotopy colimit of the constant diagram with value $*$ on the comma category $f/d$, because the restriction functor $sPsh(C)\to sPsh(f/d)$ is left Quillen. Such a homotopy colimit is weakly equivalent to the nerve of the indexing category.